# Can I show the upper part of a line that doesn't fit whole in a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

In my WinForms application, I have fixed-size multiline textboxes that can contain a variable number of lines. I want the textboxes to fit two lines plus tax in them so that only the upper part of the third line is displayed when a third line is present. Unfortunately, the third line is not displayed at all and there's just empty space instead -- you need to scroll down to see it. This is not good because the idea is to indicate to the user that scrolling down might be necessary. Is it possible to force the textbox to display the upper part of the third line?

Comment: @GrantWinney It does, but the change in color is not very impressive and the arrows are pretty small. This should be obvious to the user because the application is going to be used by service desk technicians who are generally solving three to four enduser problems at once. It's unfortunate but that's our work environment currently and it could lead to mistakes.

Comment: The comment above is a response to the question: "Isn't the scrollbar indication enough?"

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045641/using-graphics-drawstring-to-simulate-textbox-rendering) is worth a read.  Sounds like implementing this solution will require fiddling around with how the text box draws itself, which might be a deceptively difficult proposition -- although I fully agree that the out-of-the-box implementation does a poor job at indicating more text is present by not drawing that partial "third line" of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this out-of-the-box. But, there are 2 ways that I can think of by which you can achieve your goal

1. Do you really need a `TextBox` control. Can a `Label` work for you. If yes, then `Label` does not have the problem you describe above. If not, then you can use a nifty trick to always display your contents in a `Label` and switch it to a `TextBox` when a user starts typing.
2. Another way is to disable scrolling in the TextBox. Adjust the height of the `TextBox` to 3 clearly visible lines. Now drop this `TextBox` into a `Panel`. Make sure the `Panel` uses `Panel.AutoScroll = true` (you can use a separate `VerticalScrollbar` or `HorizontalScrollbar` or both if you need more control).
   Now adjust the `Panel.Height` so that only 2 full lines are visible and the 3rd line is partially visible.

You mentioned that your `TextBox`

> can contain a variable number of lines

But you also mentioned

> I want the textboxes to fit two lines plus tax in them so that only the upper part of the third line is displayed when a third line is present

So not sure what is the case. If you need to dynamically adjust the height of your `TextBox`, then look at this post to [Autoresize textbox control vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893059/autoresize-textbox-control-vertically)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use the `RichTextBox` class, which displays partial lines by default.  It is derived from the same base class as `TextBox` (`TextBoxBase`), so it should be a drop-in replacement.